# GUI Builder for Blackberry Java Plug-in for Eclipse

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

From searching online, I learnt that until July 2010, Blackberry Java Plug-in for Eclipse did not include a GUI Builder. RIM releases an update version 1.3 on Dec 23 2010. Is it the same case now? or Does The BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse v1.3 includes any kind of a GUI builder tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [current plugin page](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp) doesn't mention the inclusion of a GUI builder. It would be pretty big news if it did, as the lack of a visual layout editor is one of the biggest complaints about BlackBerry development.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, RIM have cancelled it, based on the forum post ["Visual UI Designer Plug-in for Eclipse"](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Visual-UI-Designer-Plug-in-for-Eclipse/td-p/1257323)